# Sort an array of objects by value when the key is dynamic

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array objects like so.

```
var obj = [{"UMAIR":410},
        {"ALI":2177},   
        {"JOHN":410},
        {"ANTHENY":410},
        {"FRANKLY":410},
        {"FRONTY":534},
        {"SLIM":534},
        {"ASFUND":534}];
```

I want to sort it with integer values of each object. 
I am trying to understand following code (that I have found online):

```
 obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.price - b.price;
});
```

But in this code its using **price** property, but I dont' have any specific property here.

Comment: Is that the starting or ending object? What have you tried and what was the problem?

Comment: While it is possible to find "the value of the only property", it would likely be a more useful approach overall to fix the initial data-structure. Either use a 'tuple' such as `[["JOHN", 123], ..]` (eg. the 2nd component is always the value) or an object structure with fixed keys as in `[{name: "JOHN", price: 123}, ..]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the sort function...

```
obj.sort(function(a,b) {
   return a[Object.keys(a)[0]] - b[Object.keys(b)[0]];
});
```

is Equivalent to:

```
obj.sort(function(a,b) {
   var aValue = a[Object.keys(a)[0]];
   var bValue = b[Object.keys(b)[0]];
   if (aValue > bValue)
     return 1;
   else if (aValue < bValue)
     return -1;
   else
     return 0;
});
```

Edit, Just saw your edit, yeah you did find it. 
You should also search how to extract elements from json, which in your case is
Object.keys,

It Returns an array with the key strings.

Since your Object contains a SINGLE key, you get from the array the first value (0) and then, you are making the subtraction of values from a to b.

a,b are entries of your array. they are objects.

In this [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) you can check how sorting function works

Code from the Link i provided

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if we want to do it in descending order?

Comment: You invert the a and b. Have you checked the link i provided for you?